# Invalid cast from type 'float' to type 'float*'

Tags: c++, pointers, types, any

I'm trying to create an object that can be of any type. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class thing
{
public:
    void *p;
    char type;

    thing(const char* x)
    {
        p=(char*)x;
        type=0;
    }

    thing(int x)
    {
        p=(int*)x;
        type=1;
    }

    thing(bool x)
    {
        p=(bool*)x;
        type=2;
    }

    /*
    thing(float x)
    {
        p=(float*)x;
        type=3;
    }
    */

    void print()
    {
        switch(type)
        {
        case 0:
            printf("%s\n", p);
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("%i\n", p);
            break;
        case 2:
            if(p>0)
                printf("true\n");
            else
                printf("false\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("%f\n", p);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    thing t0("Hello!");
    thing t1(123);
    thing t2(false);

    t0.print();
    t1.print();
    t2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Code is working and when I run the program, it displays:

```
Hello!
123
false
```

But if I uncomment the float constructor, the compiler writes the following error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'thing :: thing (float)': main.cpp: 30:13:
error: invalid cast from type 'float' to type 'float *'
```

Why is it not working for float type?
I use: Windows XP SP3, MinGW GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: Why not just use `boost::any`?

Comment: Did you mean to store the ADDRESS of your values that you're casting to a pointer? You can't store floating point values as a pointer.

Comment: `p=(float*)x`; you're casting a float to a float*.

Comment: Why use a `void*`? Those things are evil as they do not have any type information.

Comment: @chris Thanks, did not know about it.

Comment: Your style but done right would be a union: `union { float f; int i; ... } p;`

Comment: @olevegard I want to create an array of different types, and this is the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: @ctn I have never used the unions, will try them, too.

Comment: Also, if you want an array, you should try using vector instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Using C-Style casts is a bad idea. Prefer `static_cast` for general casting, `const_cast` when _appropriate_ and `reinterpret_cast` when _absolutely necessary_. The code in your question is currently leading you down a dark and terrifying road to **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Don't forget dynamic_cast for pointers.

Comment: @mrsimb Be careful if you use unions to store pointers. They will only store the pointer, not the underlying arrays/objects. If you'll have a `char *s` inside the string itself will be elsewhere.

Comment: ..and `dynamic_cast` for downcasting a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be casting from random types to pointer types. Even though casting `char const *`, `int`, and `bool` appear to work for you, they are not any more what you want than casting float to a pointer. In fact you should view any cast in C++ as a warning sign that you may be doing something incorrectly.

Instead you should do something like the following.

```
class thing {
private:
  union {
    char const *cs;
    int i;
    bool b;
    float f;
  };
  enum class type { cs, i, b, f } stored_type;

public:

  thing(const char* x) : cs(x), stored_type(type::cs) {}
  thing(int x)         :  i(x), stored_type(type:: i) {}
  thing(bool x)        :  b(x), stored_type(type:: b) {}
  thing(float x)       :  f(x), stored_type(type:: f) {}

  void print()
  {
    switch(stored_type)
    {
    case type::cs:
      std::printf("%s\n", cs); break;
    case type::i:
      std::printf("%i\n", i); break;
    case type::b:
      std::printf("%s\n", b ? "true" : "false"); break;
    case type::f:
      std::printf("%f\n", f); break;
    }
  }
};
```

Or better yet you could use a library that already does this for you, such as boost::variant, or boost::any.